# Elementary operations on $SL_{2} (\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

I'm reading this article: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2374319?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents , I'm trying to find a more elementary proof to Lemma 3 if considered over the integers instead of over the ring of integers of a number field. So after the right modification the lemma will be as follows:

A matrix $L_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d\\
\end{pmatrix} \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ can be transformed by 4 elementary operation (any finite number will do) to a matrix such that the top row is of the form $(x^2,y)$ where $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $y$ is a prime different then 2.

Transforming $b$ to be a prime is obvious because of Dirichlet, but i can't see how to transform $a$ to be a quadratic . Any insights?

Comment: Could you edit the definition of elementary operation into your question?